# Speed-up SciPy function applied along an axis of an Xarray DataArray

Tags: scipy, vectorization, python-xarray

I'm trying to apply a Scipy function to estimate the parameters of a probability distribution along the time axis of an Xarray Datarray (not too big, 1.7GB, but with a lot of grid points (~13M)).

Specifically my Dataset has the following structure:

```
xarray.Dataset
Dimensions: (year: 33, bnds: 2, lon: 4530, lat: 2970)

Coordinates:
lon (lon) float64 -25.24 -25.23 ... 50.22 50.24
lat (lat) float64 72.24 72.22 72.21 ... 22.77 22.76
year (year) int64 1990 1991 1992 ... 2020 2021 2022

Data variables:
time_bnds (year, bnds) datetime64[ns] ...
wgs_1984 (year) int64 ...
pr6 (year, lat, lon) float32 ...

Attributes: (0)
```

I want to apply the following function along the `year` axis of the variable `pr6`:

```
def model(ts):
    gev = scipy.stats.genextreme
    params = gev.fit(ts)    
    return np.array(params)
```

To do this for each of the DataArray grid point, I'm using the Xarray function `apply_ufunc`:

```
res = xr.apply_ufunc(model,
                     ds['pr6'],
                     input_core_dims = [["year"]],
                     output_core_dims = [["year"]],
                     exclude_dims=set(("year",)),
                     dask = 'parallelized',
                     vectorize = True,
                     output_dtypes=[float]
                     )
```

But since the dataset has a large number of points, the computation takes a long time (> 2 days). Any suggestion to speed it up?